# Extracting Proper Lake Names from Text in R

Tags: r, text, nlp, capitalization, phrase

I am trying to extract the names of Lakes from some text that I have in R. The lakes are proper (capitalized) but will require me extracting a few words on either side of the word "Lake".

I tried a few things but nothing is working quite the way I want it to... in some cases, a sentence or the article may begin with "Lake" so there is no text before it. In some cases, the proper name may be 3 words (Lake St. Clair or Red Hawk Lake).

Example code to work with:

```
text <- paste("Lake Erie is located on the border of the United States and Canada.",
          "It is located nearby to Lake St. Clair and Lake Michigan.",
          "All three lakes have a history of high levels of Phosphorus.",
          "One lake that has not yet been impacted is Lake Ontario.")
```

This was maybe the closest I got-- pulling from another stack overflow but it's still not working out.

```
context <- function(text){splittedText <-strsplit(text,'',T) print(splitted Text) data.frame(before = head(c('',splittedText),-1),words=splittedText,after=tail(c(splittedText,''),-1))}

info <- context(text)
print(subset(info, words == 'Lake')
```

I would like to get either: 1) the proper lakes names extracted ("Lake Erie", "Lake St. Clair", etc.) OR 2) a dataframe with the words before and after "Lake". Ideally the first but I'm flexible at this point.

```
before <- c("","nearby to", "Clair and","impacted is")
Lake <- c("Lake","Lake","Lake","Lake")
after <- c("Erie is","St. Clair", "Michigan ","Ontario ")
output <- data.frame(cbind(before,Lake,after)); print(output)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some rules to extract words based on the data you have. Here I get the first word after the word `"Lake"`.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(text, "Lake \\w+")[[1]]
#[1] "Lake Erie"     "Lake St"       "Lake Michigan" "Lake Ontario"
```

Or similarly in base R

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr("Lake \\w+", text))[[1]]
```

For the given `text` this almost works except for `"Lake St. Clair"` where it misses `"Clair"` part. To handle this we could have defined another rule where in case there is a dot after the next word of `"Lake"`, we extract two words but this would fail for `"Lake Michigan"` and `"Lake Ontario"` since they have full-stop following the word.

Comment: This is great. Yeah, I see three potential problems-- 1) the "." as you mention, 2) some lakes are three words without a "." (Lake Red Hawk); and 3) some lakes are named the opposite direction (Red Hawk Lake). I guess I could try to write a rule that pulls all capitalized words around "Lake"-- then the only issue would be the "."...

Answer (score 0):

With `stringi`, we can use

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(text, "Lake\\s+\\w+")[[1]]
#[1] "Lake Erie"     "Lake St"       "Lake Michigan" "Lake Ontario"
```

---

Or using `str_match_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(text, "Lake\\s+\\w+")[[1]][,1]
```